# WP8: Can this (PhoneApplicationService.RunningInBackground ) be used outside of location based app?

Tags: background, windows-phone-8, execution

From this link below, it seems that your app can still get event when app is switched to background. But it seems it is used only for location based app. Can normal app do that? I had tried to declare ID_CAP_LOCATION but still Application_RunningInBackground not get called when switch to background.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.runninginbackground(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app doesn't execute in background, unless it is continously tracking the location.

> This section lists the conditions under which the operating system
>   will deactivate an app running in the background....
>
> - The app stops actively tracking location. An app stops tracking    location by removing event handlers for the PositionChanged and
>     StatusChanged events of the Geolocator class or by calling the Stop() 
>     method of the GeoCoordinateWatcher class.

Source: [Running location-tracking apps in the background for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681691%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

You will find complete info of how to run apps in background here:

[How to run location-tracking apps in the background for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662935%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)